# Python Multi Category Ratios

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this project that requires the daily ratios per week per year like below

`Week |      Year     | Weekday | Volume
    1         2000         1         0
    1         2000         2        10
    1         2000         3        10
    2         2000         1        10
    2         2000         2         0
    1         2001         1         0
    1         2001         2        10
    1         2001         3        10
    2         2001         1        10
    2         2001         2         0`

I want the output to be something like this

`Week |      Year     | Weekday | Volume   | Ratio
    1         2000         1         0          0
    1         2000         2        10         .5
    1         2000         3        10         .5
    2         2000         1        10          1
    2         2000         2         0          0
    1         2001         1         0          0
    1         2001         2        10         .5
    1         2001         3        10         .5
    2         2001         1        10          1
    2         2001         2         0          0`

I have a current solution that does something similar to this

```
for year in years
    for week in weeks 
        ratio = week/weeklytotal
        weeklyratios = pd.concat([weeklyratios,ratio], blablabla)
```

the problem with this is that it's incredibly inefficient, especially since i have to do this process over 30k times. It ends up resulting in a 2.3 seconds run time equaling up to a 24 hour code run time.

Is there a better way to do this that can let it run faster?

Comment: how are you calculating the ratio?

Comment: @wpercy I think you mean "missing multiple colons." python doesn't need semi-colons :-)

Comment: @killian95 well that's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a groupby to compute the total volume per week. Then you can join that total volume to the original dataframe and compute the ratio in a vectorized way.

Assuming that the original dataframe is `df` (dtype being `int`):

```
   Week  Year  Weekday  Volume

0     1  2000        1       0
1     1  2000        2      10
2     1  2000        3      10
3     2  2000        1      10
4     2  2000        2       0
5     1  2001        1       0
6     1  2001        2      10
7     1  2001        3      10
8     2  2001        1      10
9     2  2001        2       0
```

you can use:

```
s = df.groupby(['Week', 'Year']).sum().drop('Weekday', axis=1)
df2 = df.set_index(['Week', 'Year']).join(s,rsuffix='_tot').sort_index(level=1)
df2['ratio'] = df2.Volume / df2.Volume_tot

print(df2)
```

gives:

```
           Weekday  Volume  Volume_tot  ratio
Week Year                                    
1    2000        1       0          20    0.0
     2000        2      10          20    0.5
     2000        3      10          20    0.5
2    2000        1      10          10    1.0
     2000        2       0          10    0.0
1    2001        1       0          20    0.0
     2001        2      10          20    0.5
     2001        3      10          20    0.5
2    2001        1      10          10    1.0
     2001        2       0          10    0.0
```

You can get your expected output with:

```
print(df2.drop('Volume_tot', axis=1).reset_index())
```

which gives:

```
   Week  Year  Weekday  Volume  ratio
0     1  2000        1       0    0.0
1     1  2000        2      10    0.5
2     1  2000        3      10    0.5
3     2  2000        1      10    1.0
4     2  2000        2       0    0.0
5     1  2001        1       0    0.0
6     1  2001        2      10    0.5
7     1  2001        3      10    0.5
8     2  2001        1      10    1.0
9     2  2001        2       0    0.0
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! This makes it 37 times faster!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute grouped operations using the indexing and `groupby` functionality in pandas.

Assuming you have a dataframe, `df`, with columns ['week','year','weekday','volume'], your solution would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit as t

# make up some data, only 1000 groups not your 30000, but it gets the point across
dates = pd.date_range(start = '2000-01-01', end = '2019-02-28', freq = 'D')
volume = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(dates.week,dates.year,dates.dayofweek,volume)),
                  columns = ['week','year','weekday','volume'])

# group
grp = df.groupby(['year','week'])
grp_vol = grp['volume'].sum()

# rename to avoid overlap in names
grp_vol.name  = 'weekly_volume'
# rejoin to calculate your ratio
df = df.join(grp_vol, on = ['year','week'])
df['ratio'] = df['volume']/df['weekly_volume']
```

And then time it for good measure

```
%timeit df['ratio'] = df['volume']/df['weekly_volume']
196 µs ± 4.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So a lot less than 24 hrs.